# How to prevent spyder from creating temp files in the same directory of the file I save

Tags: python, spyder

I installed spyder with pip (not with anaconda).
Whenever I save a .py file, spyder also generates a temp file containing a copy of the file source, in the same directory. Something like this

[image]

where each file starting with "tmp" contains the source of a different version of main.py. In the past, when I installed spyder with Anaconda, this never occurred.

Is there a way to deactivate this feature? Or at least to force spyder to save these temp files somewhere else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if you are still troubled by this issue. Are you using Dropbox or some similar services?

I've met the same problem as you did, and I found the reason on Github, see [#13041](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/13041).

If you can try to work outside Dropbox, you don't see any **tmp** files. This works for me and hope it can help you.

Comment: Yes, I think that's my problem. Thank you!